# How to print a var using echo o print in a NDK-build Android.mk file to debug compilation?

Tags: debugging, makefile, android-ndk

I'm trying to print some extra info when in compile a library using ndk-build.

For example:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
all:;echo $(LOCAL_PATH)
echo: $(LOCAL_PATH)
print:echo "i'm not working"
```

When i do ndk-build, just compile all the Android.mk, but i don't get the console echo. I have readed the GNU make info (ndk-build is just a tiny GNU make), and some post whom said echo must work using a $(VAR) but it's not working on my case.

Some idea?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Use

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
$(warning $(LOCAL_PATH))
```

Answer (score 57):

The more correct function to call is "$(info ...)" :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
$(info $(LOCAL_PATH))
```

Comment: Just an advise, using $(info) I had some compilation issues that make my compilation fail in Windows but not in Linux, just for someone experiment problem adding info. I started using CMake compilation to the detriment of Android.mk because work better

Answer (score 31):

The following displays are available in Android.mk:

- error: debug print + stop the build
- info: basic debug print
- warning: same as info but displays the line number where it's been inserted

Here below some samples:

```
$(error this is the error message that will stop the build process)
$(warning this the warning msg)
$(info this the info msg)
```

Comment: `info` is only available in NDK builds.