# lua 5.1 package.loadlib and require. gcc building windows dll

Tags: c++, c, gcc, dll, lua

I am currently working on a mod for [Noita](https://noitagame.com/), therefore I am using this

- [sock.lua](https://github.com/camchenry/sock.lua/blob/master/sock.lua)
- [lua-enet](https://leafo.net/lua-enet/#download_and_install)
- [ENet](http://enet.bespin.org/)

I am a software developer, but c, gcc and lua is new for me.

I build lua-enet on my own with the following command using msys2 (to be clear I used mingw32) on windows 10 inside of the current master github folder:

```
gcc -O -shared -o enet.dll enet.c -lenet -llua5.1 -lws2_32 -lwinm --verbose
```

Additionally I had to add the necessary files like the header files:
[image]

and

[image]

I did this several times, because I had errors like

> The specified module could not be found.

> enet is not a valid Win32 application

But the gcc command above worked then while running Noita in DevBuild / Debug mode.
I was able to debug it with [Decoda](https://unknownworlds.com/decoda/) and saw the library was loaded.

**But** when I run Noita via Steam I get the following error:

> Lua (DoFile) error at 'mods/noita-mp/init.lua': error loading module 'enet1317_lua-enet-master21-10-2015_lua5-1_32bit' from file 'mods\noita-mp\files\libs\enet1317_lua-enet-master21-10-2015_lua5-1_32bit.dll':
> Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

[image]

- enet.dll 64bit version one. (didnt work)
- enet1317_lua-enet-master21-10-2015_lua5-1_32bit.dll 32bit version, build with the gcc command above. (only works in debug mode)

Additional printing:

```
Mod enabled: noita-mp 0
LUA: file_util.lua | Noitas root absolute path set to C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Noita   
LUA: ;.\?.lua;C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Noita\lua\?.lua;C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Noita\lua\?\init.lua;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\?.luac;mods\noita-mp\files\libs\?.lua;C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Noita\mods\noita-mp\files\libs\?.lua;    
LUA: .\?.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Noita\?.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Noita\loadall.dll;mods\noita-mp\files\libs\?.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Noita\mods\noita-mp\files\libs\?.dll;   
LUA: Trying to load enet c library by file name with 'enet1317_lua-enet-master21-10-2015_lua5-1_32bit.dll' loading.. Does file exists? false    
LUA: nil    
LUA: Trying to load enet c library by relative path with 'mods\noita-mp\files\libs\enet1317_lua-enet-master21-10-2015_lua5-1_32bit.dll' loading.. Does file exists? true    
LUA: nil    
LUA: Trying to load enet c library by absolute path with 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Noita\mods\noita-mp\files\libs\enet1317_lua-enet-master21-10-2015_lua5-1_32bit.dll' loading.. Does file exists? true    
LUA: nil    
LUA: Trying to load enet c library by absolute path with 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Noita\mods\noita-mp\files\libs\enet1317_lua-enet-master21-10-2015_lua5-1_32bit.dll' loading.. Does file exists? true    
LUA: nil    
LUA: enet c library 'enet1317_lua-enet-master21-10-2015_lua5-1_32bit.dll' was loaded by require load.   
Lua (DoFile) error at 'mods/noita-mp/init.lua': error loading module 'enet1317_lua-enet-master21-10-2015_lua5-1_32bit' from file 'mods\noita-mp\files\libs\enet1317_lua-enet-master21-10-2015_lua5-1_32bit.dll':
    Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
```

init.lua

```
dofile("mods/noita-mp/files/scripts/util/util.lua")

SetNoitaRootAbsolutePath()

-- Need to add module package to package path, because relative paths are not working
package.path = package.path .. ";"
.. string.gsub(GetRelativePathOfRequiredLibs() .. "/?.lua;", "/", "\\")
.. string.gsub(GetAbsolutePathOfRequiredLibs() .. "/?.lua;", "/", "\\")
print(package.path)

package.cpath = package.cpath .. ";"
.. string.gsub(GetRelativePathOfRequiredLibs() .. "/?.dll;", "/", "\\")
.. string.gsub(GetAbsolutePathOfRequiredLibs() .. "/?.dll;", "/", "\\")
print(package.cpath)


ModMagicNumbersFileAdd("mods/noita-mp/files/data/magic_numbers.xml")

local enet = nil
if enet == nil then
    local fileName = "enet1317_lua-enet-master21-10-2015_lua5-1_32bit.dll"
    print("Trying to load enet c library by file name with '" .. fileName .. "' loading.. Does file exists? " .. tostring(FileExists(fileName)))
    enet = package.loadlib(fileName, "luaopen_enet")

    if not enet then
        print(tostring(enet))
        local rel_path = GetRelativePathOfRequiredLibs() .. "/" .. fileName
        rel_path = string.gsub(rel_path, "/", "\\")
        print("Trying to load enet c library by relative path with '" .. rel_path .. "' loading.. Does file exists? " .. tostring(FileExists(rel_path)))
        enet = package.loadlib(rel_path, "luaopen_enet")
    end

    if not enet then
        print(tostring(enet))
        local abs_path = GetAbsolutePathOfRequiredLibs() .. "/" .. fileName
        abs_path = string.gsub(abs_path, "/", "\\")
        print("Trying to load enet c library by absolute path with '" .. abs_path .. "' loading.. Does file exists? " .. tostring(FileExists(abs_path)))
        enet = package.loadlib(abs_path, "luaopen_enet")
    end

    if not enet then
        print(tostring(enet))
        local abs_path = [[C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Noita\mods\noita-mp\files\libs\enet1317_lua-enet-master21-10-2015_lua5-1_32bit.dll]]
        print("Trying to load enet c library by absolute path with '" .. abs_path .. "' loading.. Does file exists? " .. tostring(FileExists(abs_path)))
        enet = package.loadlib(abs_path, "luaopen_enet")
    end

    if enet then
        print("enet c library '" .. fileName .. "' was loaded by function load.")
        enet()
    else
        print(tostring(enet))
        print("enet c library '" .. fileName .. "' was loaded by require load.")
        require("enet1317_lua-enet-master21-10-2015_lua5-1_32bit")
    end
end
```

I already tried to put the enet*.dll to a different location like a separated ssd, in noitas root folder, but didnt change anything.

Anyone out here with an idea to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that I had to use lua51 dll provided by Noita and the correct headers related to Noitas luaJit used version 2.0.4.

For everyone stumbling about this, this is how I build the enet.dll

```
# Introduction to build enet + lua-enet with msys2

## MINGW32

1. start MINGW32 by msys2
2. make sure configure is installed:
    - go to your msys2 installation (C:\msys64\)
    - use windump search and search for "configure"
    - found it in msys64\usr\share\libtool

## ENet

3. download (latest) source code: <https://github.com/lsalzman/enet/releases/tag/v1.3.17>
4. go to your ENet source code download zip and extract to enet-1.3.17

## MINGW32 again

5. in MINGW32 go to that extracted folder (cd "D:\______BACKUP\NoitaMP_repo\NoitaMP\dll building\enet-1.3.17")
6. look into README [and Makefile.am if you are interested] (cat README)
7. run "autoreconf -vfi" in MINGW32 inside of enet-1.3.17 folder
8. run "./configure && make && make install" in MINGW32 inside of enet-1.3.17 folder

## lua-enet

9. download latest version which looks like to be master branch, so download the master branch and keep the date in mind: https://github.com/leafo/lua-enet
10. extract that zip to lua-enet-master_21-10-2015
11. take a look here to know how to build the lua lib, but let me explain in a sec: https://github.com/leafo/lua-enet/issues/1#issuecomment-1960709
12. do not use lua51.dll which is provided by lua installation, use Noitas lua51.dll! See Noitas root installation path.
13. rename lua-enet-master_21-10-2015 to lua-enet-master_21-10-2015_ENet1-3-17_Noita-lua51-dll
14. copy those files
    - ..\enet-1.3.17\.libs\libenet.a
    - ..\enet-1.3.17\include\enet\*
    - ..\Noita\lua51.dll and rename it to noitalua51.dll
        into lua-enet-master_21-10-2015_ENet1-3-17_Noita-lua51-dll
15. download luajit 2.0.4 (because mod community verifed that noita dev team used 2.0.4)
16. copy those files (D:\______BACKUP\NoitaMP_repo\NoitaMP\dll building\LuaJIT-2.0.4)
    - ..\src\lua.h
    - ..\src\luaconf.h
    - ..\src\lualib.h
    - ..\src\lauxlib.h
        into lua-enet-master_21-10-2015_ENet1-3-17_Noita-lua51-dll

## MINGW32 building lua-enet.dll

16. go to your lua-enet-master_21-10-2015_ENet1-3-17_Noita-lua51-dll directory inside of MINGW32 (cd "D:\______BACKUP\NoitaMP_repo\NoitaMP\dll building\lua-enet-master_21-10-2015_ENet1-3-17_Noita-lua51-dll")
17. run "gcc -O -shared -o enet.dll enet.c -lenet -lws2_32 -lwinmm -mwindows -m32 -L /D/______BACKUP/NoitaMP_repo/NoitaMP/dll_building/lua-enet-master_21-10-2015_ENet1-3-17_Noita-lua51-dll/lib -lnoitalua51 --verbose"
18. copy enet.dll into your mods folder. i.e. Noita\mods\noita-mp\files\libs\enet.dll
```