# Overcoming "undefined reference" error in cmake - a package is being requested by cmake and I have the package available

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

cmake says I have an undefined reference to `gzopen64@ZLIB_1.2.3.3`. I built zlib 1.2.3.3 from source, added the include directory to `CPATH`, added the lib directory to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and pasted `libz.so.1.2.3.3` into my build directory. I am still stuck on this error. Is there any other way I can lead cmake to the zlib 1.2.3.3 build?

**Edit**
OK here's the full error message:

```
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target utilscore
[  4%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/utilscore.dir/CFDMesh.cpp.o    
[  8%] Linking CXX static library libutilscore.a
[  8%] Built target utilscore
Scanning dependencies of target nalu_preprocess
[ 13%] Building CXX object src/preprocessing/CMakeFiles/nalu_preprocess.dir/PreProcessingTask.cpp.o
[ 17%] Building CXX object src/preprocessing/CMakeFiles/nalu_preprocess.dir/NDTW2D.cpp.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object src/preprocessing/CMakeFiles/nalu_preprocess.dir/SamplingPlanes.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object src/preprocessing/CMakeFiles/nalu_preprocess.dir/ABLFields.cpp.o
[ 30%] Building CXX object src/preprocessing/CMakeFiles/nalu_preprocess.dir/ChannelFields.cpp.o
[ 34%] Building CXX object src/preprocessing/CMakeFiles/nalu_preprocess.dir/RotateMesh.cpp.o
[ 39%] Building CXX object src/preprocessing/CMakeFiles/nalu_preprocess.dir/BdyIOPlanes.cpp.o
[ 43%] Building CXX object src/preprocessing/CMakeFiles/nalu_preprocess.dir/PreProcessDriver.cpp.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object src/preprocessing/CMakeFiles/nalu_preprocess.dir/nalu_preprocess.cpp.o
[ 52%] Linking CXX executable nalu_preprocess
CMakeFiles/nalu_preprocess.dir/BdyIOPlanes.cpp.o: In function `stk::mesh::Bucket::begin_nodes(unsigned long) const':
/projects/windsim/exawind/SharedSoftwareA/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos6-x86_64/gcc-5.2.0/trilinos-develop-aeyspdjmeoo5inhcb7cpaojmrds7f6tt/include/stk_mesh/base/Bucket.hpp:306: undefined reference to `stk::mesh::Bucket::check_for_invalid_connectivity_request(stk::mesh::ConnectivityType const*) const'
/projects/windsim/exawind/SharedSoftwareA/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos6-x86_64/gcc-5.2.0/libxml2-2.9.4-ek3x27doaf3vg2izm363k755zy7nd67z/lib/libxml2.so.2: undefined reference to `gzopen64@ZLIB_1.2.3.3'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/preprocessing/nalu_preprocess] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/preprocessing/CMakeFiles/nalu_preprocess.dir/all] Error 2
```

I understand there are similar questions about undefined reference errors. I'm not convinced this is a duplicate question. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) nicely lays out all the possible causes of an undefined reference. I didn't find one that matched my specific situation, where a package is being requested by cmake and I have the package available.

Comment: Can you paste the full error message?

Comment: did you check the file read permissions when you copied over the directory?

Comment: @0x5453 I posted it

Comment: @DashWinterson I ran `chmod -R 777` on the `zlib` directory and in the build directory, after rerunning my `cmake` workflow, right before running make. I get the same error.

Comment: can we see where in the makefile you define ld lib path as well? sorry just trying to get all the info

Comment: @DashWinterson Thanks for your questions. I don't do that in the make file. I added the paths with `export CPATH=/path/to/zlib/include:$CPATH` and `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH =/path/to/zlib/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: when you echo the LD_LIBRARY_PATH from inside the makefile does it spit out the correct path?

Comment: " I ran `chmod -R 777`" - why on earth would you set such broad permissions? And why set the execute (on files) bit (which is search for directories) so indiscriminately? For all users none the less.

Comment: @DashWinterson Yes. I used this technique to do that https://stackoverflow.com/a/25817631/3474956

Comment: I found evidence that the lxml and zlib libs might conflict here: https://github.com/lukeroth/gdal/issues/15