# Print variables from Android.mk/Android.bp for a specific module in AOSP

Tags: android, android-source

Is there a way to print out build variables from Android.mk or Android.bp files for a specific module in AOSP. I am interested in the variable LOCAL_SRC_FILES for some modules.

I have played around with the two commands below. They seem however only to operate on the main build and is not usable for modules. I need it for Android P and unfortunate the first one is also deprecated.

> $ CALLED_FROM_SETUP=true BUILD_SYSTEM=build/core make -f build/core/config.mk dumpvar-LOCAL_SRC_FILES
>
> $ build/soong/soong_ui.bash --dumpvar-mode LOCAL_SRC_FILES

Is there a way to extract the LOCAL_-variables without scripting yourself?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467718/how-to-print-out-a-variable-in-makefile