# How to print environment variables from makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

After reading this answer:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467718/how-to-print-out-a-variable-in-makefile/29704625), of using

```
$(info    text…)
$(info $(var))
```

I have tried it in makefile:

```
.PHONY: all

all: ; $(info $(var))
```

(where the `var` was set outside in bash), I got output:

make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
So how can I print variables defined outside of makefile, in makefile?

Comment: Please provide a complete set of commands, cut and pasted.  For example how was `var` actually set?  How did you run make?  What is the name of your makefile?  I recommend you change your output so that it prints more than just a blank line if the variable is not set, something like `$(info var = '$(var)')` so it's easier to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

How to print environment variables from makefile?

You can do exactly as you say in the question. For example:

Here's the Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all
all: ; $(info VAR='$(VAR)')
```

Now set the environment variable VAR on the command line before running make:

```
$ VAR=foo make
VAR='foo'
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

Or export it and then run make:

```
$ export VAR=bar
$ make
VAR='bar'
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

So, you need to look elsewhere to find out why this is not working for you.

Note that you don't need to put the `$(info)` in a recipe; For example here's a one line makefile printing an environment variable:

Makefile:

```
$(info VAR='$(VAR)')
```

Set the environment variable VAR and run make:

```
$ VAR=foo make
VAR='foo'
make: *** No targets. Stop.
```